# Subtract a constant from all numbers in a file using a Perl one-liner

Tags: regex, perl, command-line

I have a file that contains chess moves like these-

```
45. Qxf7+ Kh8 46. Qf8+ (46. Qf6+ Kh7 47. c6 (47. Kh2 Qe8 48. Qf4 Qd7
) 47... Bb5+ 48. Kh2 Qe8 49. c7 Bc6 50. Qd8 (50. Kg3 Bb7 51. Qd6 Qe4 52. Qd7+
Kh6 53. Qd2+ Kg7 54. f3 Qe5+ 55. Kf2 Qc5+ 56. Qe3 Qb4)) 46... Kh7 47. Qf4 Bb5+
(47... Bc4+ 48. Kh2 Bd5 49. c6 Bxc6 50. Qc7+ Kh6...
```

Instead of the moves being numbered from 45, I would like them to be numbered from 1 onwards like this -

```
 1. Qxf7+ Kh8 2. Qf8+ (2. Qf6+ Kh7 3. c6 ...
```

The problem is, I can't simply subtract 44 from all numbers in the file, since the moves themselves contain digits, like Kh8, Bc6, etc. I can detect the move number using the pattern `[0-9]+\.`, but how to replace it with `(number - 44)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)\.\s/($1-44).". "/ge' file.txt
```

Comment: What does the /ge mean?

Comment: @Wes - `g`lobally and `e`xecute the substitution code.

Comment: If the string does end with `Kh6...`, then that substitution wouldn't work. It would perform the substitution giving `Kh-38`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use `\b` to ensure the digits are NOT preceded by letters

```
perl -p -e's/\b(\d+)/$1-44/ge'
```

Then you don't need to carry the `.` and space into the replacement expression

Answer (score 0):

Improvement on accepted solution:

```
perl -pe's/(\d+)(?=\.\s)/$1-44/ge'
```

Usage:

```
perl -i~ -pe'...' file.txt            Change in place with backup
perl -i -pe'...' file.txt             Change in place without backup
perl -pe'...' file.in >file.out       Read from file
perl -pe'...' <file.in >file.out      Read from STDIN
```